# Ruby on Rails with_option cannot call class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, methods, with-statement

I have a problem calling class method from the **with_option** block with validations:

Model:

```
  class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :field

     with_options :if => "<not important>" do |step|
       ... bunch of validations
       step.validates :field, :inclusion => {:within => Model.field}
     end
  private
      def self.field
        (1..10)
      end
  end
```

And it returns: undefined method `field' for #Class:0x5f394a8

*self.class.field* also doesn't work.

What is wrong with it ? How to fix it ?

Big big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah. Nevermind. Solved in myself. Just encapsulate Model.field with proc or lambda.